# Nested Logic App - Error when parameterizing the workflow id in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to parameterize the workflow id of a nested Logic app like so:

```
"host":{  
   "triggerName":"manual",
   "workflow":{  
      "id":"@parameters('NestedWorkflowId')"
   }
}
```

Defining the workflow id parameter:

```
"parameters":{  
   "NestedWorkflowId":{  
      "type": "String"
   }
}
```

Setting the parameter value:

```
"parameters":{  
   "NestedWorkflowId":{  
      "value":"[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('SubscriptionId'), '/resourceGroups/', variables('ResourceGroupName'), '/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/', variables('NestedLogicAppName'))]"
   }
}
```

But doing this I get this error:

[image]

Comment: This is not possible. it expects full qualified logic app name. it does not even allow /subscriptions/xxxxxresourceGroups/teslogicapp/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/@triggerBody()?['NestedWorkflowId']

Comment: Okay, thanks. That's disappointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you switch between design and code view in Visual Studio using the Logic Apps extension. However, I was able to deploy the Logic App without issues, so it appears to be a bug in the extension's validation.